# Ipad viewport portrait issue

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a web page that comes up on an ipad. My body web page has a width of 960px and a variable height.

I added this meta for the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

I want to see 100% of my web page on the sceen. It works well in landscape but I am not able to find how to modify my viewport to see 100% of my webpage in landscape and in portrait.

Currently I see 60% of the width of my webpage in portrait.

I do not want to add a JS script or media queries. My webpage is not responsive.

Comment: Provide your html page demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reach my goal by using this code :

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px)
and (orientation: portrait) {
    body {
    width: 768px;
    }
}
```

Apparently it is a specific code for Ipad but it work well with Nexus 9.0 and surface too.

If somebody has JS script to do exactly the same I would be interested to check it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a static width, and the iPad has a smaller width in portrait mode. Solving this without adjusting your static width will be impossible. Maybe you should still consider JS or media queries. Here is a website with more information about dimensions: http://www.websitedimensions.com/

Comment: Ok I checked your website and I tried to fix my width at 768 but it was not the result I want. What about media queries ? I really do not know them, do you have a website to help me resolving my issue with them  ?